# ‘Non-Induced’ Left Regular Representations of $ C^{*} $-Dynamical Systems

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, induced-representations, crossed-products

In what follows, a ‘$ * $-representation’ always means a *non-degenerate $ * $-representation*.

---

Let $ (\mathscr{A},G,\alpha) $ be a $ C^{*} $-dynamical system, and let $ \pi: \mathscr{A} \to B(\mathcal{H}) $ be a faithful $ * $-representation of $ \mathscr{A} $ on a Hilbert space $ \mathcal{H} $. Define an associated faithful $ * $-representation $ \tilde{\pi}: \mathscr{A} \to B({L^{2}}(G,\mathcal{H})) $ and a unitary group representation $ \lambda: G \to U({L^{2}}(G,\mathcal{H})) $ as follows.

> For all $ a \in \mathscr{A} $, $ g \in G $, $ x \in G $ and $ \xi \in {L^{2}}(G,\mathcal{H}) $,
>   \begin{align*}
> [[\tilde{\pi}(a)](\xi)](x) & \stackrel{\text{def}}{=}
> [\pi({\alpha_{x^{-1}}}(a))](\xi(x)), \\
> [[\lambda(g)](\xi)](x)     & \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \xi(g^{-1} x).
> \end{align*}

$ \lambda $ is usually called the *left regular representation of $ G $*.

It is well-known that the pair $ (\tilde{\pi},\lambda) $ — called the *left regular representation induced by $ \pi $* — is a covariant representation of $ (\mathscr{A},G,\alpha) $ on $ {L^{2}}(G,\mathcal{H}) $ and that the integrated form $ \tilde{\pi} \rtimes \lambda $ is a faithful $ * $-representation of the twisted convolution $ * $-algebra $ ({C_{c}}(G,\mathscr{A}),\star,^{*}) $ on $ {L^{2}}(G,\mathcal{H}) $.

It is also well-known that $ \tilde{\pi} \rtimes \lambda $ extends uniquely to a faithful $ * $-representation of the reduced crossed product $ C^{*} $-algebra $ \mathscr{A} \rtimes_{\alpha,\text{r}} G $ on $ {L^{2}}(G,\mathcal{H}) $.

> **My question:** Suppose that we have a faithful $ * $-representation $ \rho: \mathscr{A} \to B({L^{2}}(G,\mathcal{H})) $ that is not associated to $ \pi $, i.e. is not of the form $ \tilde{\pi} $, for any faithful $ * $-representation $ \pi: \mathscr{A} \to B(\mathcal{H}) $. Suppose further that the pair $ (\rho,\lambda) $ — which I shall call a *non-induced left regular representation* — is a covariant representation of $ (\mathscr{A},G,\alpha) $ on $ {L^{2}}(G,\mathcal{H}) $. Then is it necessarily true that the integrated form $ \rho \rtimes \lambda $ gives rise to a faithful $ * $-representation of $ \mathscr{A} \rtimes_{\alpha,\text{r}} G $ on $ {L^{2}}(G,\mathcal{H}) $?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no in two ways. Let $G$ be a discrete group and consider the trivial action of $G$ on the reduced group $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra $\mathrm{C}^*_{\mathrm{r}}G$. The pair of the right regular representation $\rho\colon \mathrm{C}^*_{\mathrm{r}}G\to B(\ell_2G)$ and the left regular representation $\lambda\colon G\to U(\ell_2G)$ is covariant. The resulting $*$-homomorphism $\rho\rtimes\lambda$ is continuous on the reduced crossed product (which is nothing but the minimal tensor product $\mathrm{C}^*_{\rho}G \otimes_{\min} \mathrm{C}^*_{\lambda}G$) if and only if $G$ is amenable. It is faithful on the algebraic tensor product $\mathrm{C}^*_{\rho}G \otimes_{\mathrm{alg}} \mathrm{C}^*_{\lambda}G$ if and only if $G$ is ICC.